# How to approach a Java event queue

Tags: java, events, concurrency, event-loop

Hello everyone and thanks for the time you dedicated in advance!

I have a problem I'm not sure how to approach in Java. Let's say I have a user interface that creates events that have to be "executed" in a specific time in the future, which may vary from a couple of minutes in the future to several days.

I have though of creating a class (let's say EventHandler) that implementa Runnable, and then a ConcurrentLinkedList that stores those instantiations ordered by the time they should be executed, from least in advance to most in advance. After that, a thread that peeks the queue, and If system time is greater than expected execution time, start the process.

Problem is, aside of concurrency problems associated with list, that the peek thread consumes CPU time. So I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution, considering there may be hundreds of events scheduled in a single second interval. Also, I'm using Hibernate with MongoDb to store stuff, if that affects at all.

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm open to all other solutions you may think of, as long as it solves the "queue events and execute them in the time they are set to"

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing [`DelayQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html).

Comment: DelayQueue and keep a separate Object of the earliest expiration time so you don't poll too often.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about that Queue. I've tried with it and I think I'm happy with the result. I'll have to check and think deeper on the real full implementation of the program, and if I can adapt it to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach is to use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

```
int corePoolSize = 1;// for sequential execution of tasks
// for parallel execution use Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); 

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
...
Runnable command1 = ...
executor.schedule(command1, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // execute in couple of minutes
Runnable command2 = ...
executor.schedule(command2, 7, TimeUnit.DAYS); // execute in 7 days
```